# How to set Xamarin MonoMac project so its build outputs .app package instead of .exe?

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, monomac

I am trying to get Mac package (.app) as build output when building MonoMac project in Xamarin. This project is actually a default one - it only displays an empty window and can be created in Xamarin through: *Add New Project...*, select *Mac(open source)* and then *MonoMac Project (C#)*.

Project builds with no errors but build output is .exe file. **How can I set project build so it outputs .app package instead of .exe?** I looked at *Project Options-->Build-->General* where could select *Compile Target* as *Executable/Executable with GUI/...*but that's not what I need. Also looked at Xamarin studio *Preferences-->Projects-->Build* but it didn't help either.

My setup:

```
 - Xamarin studio 4.0.3 (build 13) which includes free MonoMac 
 - Xcode 4.6.1 (2067, build 4H512); gcc installed 
 - Mono frameworks 2.10.9 and 2.10.12 
 - all running on Mac OS X 10.7.5
```

Build output for Debug|x86 build configuration:
[image: Build output for Debug|x86 build configuration:]

Comment: It builds a `.app` by default, what have you done to the configuration?

Comment: Nothing - used only default settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look where the exe is generated:

/Users/rolf/Projects/test-project/bin/Debug/**test-project.app**/Contents/MonoBundle/test-project.exe

The output is always an .app package, the exe is just a file that goes into the .app package.

Comment: Rolf, that's what I expected I would get but only exe is generated. Please see screenshot of `bin` folder I added to my question.

Comment: That's also what I see. How to get from an EXE to an APP?

Comment: @Krumelur: I can't reproduce this - can you file a bug at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com?

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. I created a "C# conosole project" and that results in an EXE. The (Mono)Mac project creates an app bundle as expected.

Comment: @Rolf Could not reproduce this behaviour with later versions of Xamarin Studio - all works fine, getting .app as an output so marking your answer as accepted.

Comment: I still have this problem. When I start a new empty console project and compile, I only get an .exe. How did you guys get the app file? I don't want an app with a GUI, I just want a console app.