# Can I create a console application using Xamarin.Mac?

Tags: macos, console, terminal, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I just purchased Xamarin.Mac in an effort to create a cross platform console utility. I figured this would be trivial but I am missing something.

How can I create and what do I need to do to deploy a simple `Console.WriteLine("Hello World");` app using Xamarin.Mac?

here is the result I am looking for from the console in any folder on my mac.

```
$ my_xammac_app
Hello World
$
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set Xamarin MonoMac project so its build outputs .app package instead of .exe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853994/how-to-set-xamarin-monomac-project-so-its-build-outputs-app-package-instead-of)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new Mac project and simply use the assemblies you need.

You can delete the UI files that a new project contains (such as the .xibs and the files that go along with that). You don't have to use them.

Answer (score 3):

Use File - C# - Console Project to create console c# application

Comment: This does not generate a native binary it appears to be dependent on mono

Comment: Of course, it dependent on mono! It have .exe extension. It's like .NET. To run .NET programm, you need install .NET runtime. Xamarin.Mac builded to create mono executables!

Comment: Looks like it's now under Other -> .NET -> Console Project

Answer (score 0):

The options are described here:

[http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:Running_Mono_Applications](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3aRunning_Mono_Applications)