# Xamarin C# Cross Platform Application

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I am new to using Xamarin and have always used Visual Studio, however I now require to develop a desktop application which will run on both Mac and Windows, OR at least a package which will let me package for both.

I have created a GTK 2.0 Project, connected to a MySQL database etc and all is fine, however I can only see options to create a .exe and no .dmg file for OS X but the debugger lets me run it on my Mac.

Does anyone have any ideas or pointers?

Comment: Seriously, Afternoon was removed from my question..

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  Do you just want to know how to create a DMG?

Comment: Your question was edited to remove unnecessary verbiage - see [Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Comment: Are you using Xamarin.Mac or Cocoa# ?

Comment: Xamarin.Mac and yes I need to create .exe and .dmg for my application.

Comment: you most likely don't want to create a `.dmg` file. A `.dmg` file is a disk image, somewhat comparable to an `.iso` file. Disk images are used for distribution of an app. What you want to create is an `.app` bundle, which is (sort of) the equivalent of a Windows executable.

Answer (score 0):

We use Xamarin.Mac to enable us to develop a Windows and Mac client using c#.
We chose to re-build the core code in Xamarin Studio and use interfaces to abstract the OS dependent code.
We share 90% of our code in the Xamarin.Mac/VS solutions.

Do let me know if I'm helping... if so I can provide more detail if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following link on how to create an `.app` bundle with Xamarin:

[How to set Xamarin MonoMac project so its build outputs .app package instead of .exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853994/how-to-set-xamarin-monomac-project-so-its-build-outputs-app-package-instead-of)

An app bundle is basically a special kind of folder structure that contains all app data, including e.g. graphical resources, configuration files, localisations, etc...

A `.dmg` file is used for distribution and can be created using other tools like Apple's own [Disk Utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_Utility), once you've created the app.